# Using Regular Expression to extract an Object and its Attributes

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I am using a `List<T>` result that contains strings such as
- to simplify it let me use such words, but the scheme is the same

```
01:01 A car consists of : wheels, engine, seats, 2 screws, a cotton lamp
01:02 A bike consists of : wheels
01:03 A car consists of : wheels, engine, seats, speakers, 5 screws, an indicator light
01:04 A small truck consists of : wheels, engine, seats, bed
```

So a pseudo matcher and desired output would be.

```
00-99:0-99(space)A|An(space){get the car/bike or any other as object}(space)consists(space)of(space):{get the elements in here exploding the commas as attributes}
```

For now I use in a foreach loop, that goes though my list and then writes the lines into the textbox.

```
Foreach(Message _msg in _objects.Messages){
    richTextBox1.AppendText(_msg.Text);
}
```

Pseudo displayer which adds the whole sentences into my textbox.

```
Foreach(Message _msg in _objects.Messages){
    richTextBox1.AppendText(parsefunction(_msg.Text));
}

parse function
{ 
    count(the elements exploaded , and list them)
    remove the unwanted parts of text
}
```

Once the objects and attributes are extracted, I want to sum them based on whether they include a count or not, and remove a/an from them. This is partly where I am stuck.

The desired output would be - summing any duplicates, and quantities that appear

```
2x Car
4x Wheels
3x Engine
3x Seats
7x Screws
1x Cotton Lamp
1x Bike
1x Speakers
1x Indicator Light
1x Small Truck
1x Bed
```

Could you point me at least `Regex` and maybe I manage to count the rest myself and share with when done. I assume it has to be a function that will be called in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with (I'm sure it can be improved):

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> ParseData(List<string> data)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\d]{2}:[\d]{2} A[n]? ([a-zA-Z\s]+) consists of : ([a-zA-Z,\s0-9]+)$");
    var elementMap = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(data[i]);
        var attributes = match.Groups[2].Value.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (match.Success && match.Groups[1].Value.Length > 0)
            elementMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(match.Groups[1].Value, attributes));
    }

    return elementMap;
}

public static Dictionary<string, int> GetIndexedData(List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> data)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> displayObjects = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> item in data)
    {
        if (displayObjects.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            displayObjects[item.Key]++;
        else
            displayObjects.Add(item.Key, 1);

        foreach (string key2 in item.Value)
        {
            string[] attributeValues = key2.Split(' ');
            int add = 1;
            string addValue = key2;
            int c = 0;

            if (attributeValues.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(attributeValues[0], out c))
            {
                add = c;
                addValue = attributeValues[1];
            }

            if (addValue.Substring(0, 2) == "a ")
                addValue = addValue.Substring(2);
            else if (addValue.Substring(0, 3) == "an ")
                addValue = addValue.Substring(3);

            if (displayObjects.ContainsKey(addValue))
                displayObjects[addValue] += add;
            else
                displayObjects.Add(addValue, add);
        }
    }

    return displayObjects;
}
```

Use with:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
data.Add("01:01 A car consists of : wheels, engine, seats, 2 screws, a cotton lamp");
data.Add("01:02 A bike consists of : wheels");
data.Add("01:03 A car consists of : wheels, engine, seats, speakers, 5 screws, an indicator light");
data.Add("01:04 A small truck consists of : wheels, engine, seats, bed");
var elementMap = ParseData(data);

var displayObjects = GetIndexedData(elementMap);

foreach (string key in displayObjects.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + displayObjects[key]);
}
```

Basically; this `Regex` pattern (`^[\d]{2}:[\d]{2} A[n]? ([a-zA-Z\s]+) consists of : ([a-zA-Z,\s0-9]+)$`) will match anything constructed **exactly** as you indicated. All you have to do with it is:

```
var match = regex.Match(data[i]);
// 'match.Groups[1].Value' is the name of the item
// 'match.Groups[2].Value' is the comma-separated list

// The following line will split all the attributes on ', ' therefore leaving them as just the words. (`wheels`, `engine`, `seats`)
var attributes = match.Groups[2].Value.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Do what you would like with all this information.

This makes the following assumptions:

1. The data will always consist of two numbers (`[\d]{2}`), a colon (`:`), and two more numbers (`[\d]{2}`), a space (), an a (`A`) and optionally an n (`[n]?`) (for `A` or `An`) and another space (); all of this at the very beginning of the line (`^`)
2. The name of the `object` (`([a-zA-Z\s]+)` can consist of:

   1. Letters (`a-z`, `A-Z`)
   2. Spaces (`\s`)
   3. At least one of these characters, and as many as possible
3. The next words **will** be a space (), `consists of`, a space (), and a colon (`:`).
4. The words of the `attributes` (`([a-zA-Z,\s0-9]+)`) can consist of:

   1. Letters (`a-z`, `A-Z`)
   2. Commas (`,`)
   3. Spaces (`\s`)
   4. Numbers (`0-9`)
   5. At least one of these characters, and as many as possible
5. After these attributes will be the end of the string (`$`)

Lastly, this assumes that the `attributes` are not `null` or `nothing` - there is **at least one** character in the `attributes`.

Also, there is **no** error checking here. You should add that as needed.

Comment: All seems to be working I added some twists to make it win forms, but where should the counting of elements be? In for loop attributes? I thought I could put the elements in 2 lists : 1 types and second the list with  separated coma elements, but isn't this the longer way of doing it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You could easily do this a multitude of ways. I'll add a couple examples.

Comment: And what you mean by an error checker? I never did this before

Comment: Now it shows Car - wheels, engine, seats next line Bike - wheels

Comment: @Kavvson I rewrote it as a `function`. You should have an easier time using it. And by `error checking`, I mean that I *make **no** attempts* to catch or handle **any** errors with `input`.

Comment: Let me test it and give feedback and later u can direct me to some article about error handling

Comment: The best overloaded method match for
 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.ParseData(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' 
has some invalid arguments || var elementMap = ParseData(_msg.Text); used in my loop - yes it has to be there ;)

Comment: You should be *quite* capable of determining the issue with that error. You **cannot** pass a `string` object, you **must** pass a `List<string>` object: split your input on each newline and then add each line to a `List<string>` to send to the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78340/discussion-between-kavvson-and-ebrown).